# Flask - Return None And HTTP Response 204

Tags: python, flask

My backend is a RestfulAPI, I send request from my React website.
I want to return an empty response with HTTP code 204 ('No Content').

I have a route (API method):

```
@register_bp.route('/auth/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    register_dto = RegisterDTO.from_dict(request.get_json())
    user: User = UsersConverter.convert_register_dto_to_entity(register_dto)
    if UserDbMethods.does_user_with_username_exist(user.username):
        raise DuplicatedException('This username is used, please choose other username')
    if UserDbMethods.does_user_with_email_exist(user.email):
        raise DuplicatedException('This email is used by another username.')
    if not AuthUtils.is_strong_password(register_dto.password):
        raise BadRequestException('Your password is not strong, please choose stronger password')
    user.set_password_and_hash(register_dto.password)
    UserDbMethods.create_user(user)
    return
```

I want to return a None and in 'after_app_request' to handle the response and set the HTTP code to 204.
But flask fails when returning a None.

`The view function for 'register_api.register' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

If I return an empty string '' it works but I want to return a None. Empty string is not nice to the eye.

Tried to return None or return. Excepted to handle it in the after_Request.

Comment: return "Registered successfully"  or return "None"

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
from flask import Flask, request, g

# your code ...

g.http_status_code = 204
return "Registered successfully"  # return a message

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    if hasattr(g, 'http_status_code'):
        response.status_code = g.http_status_code
    return response
```

Comment: Is this g a good practice? I also can just return an empty string or do EMPTY_STRING = '' and return it. I want the best practice :)

Comment: Is a common and accepted practice in Flask applications,